# What is the best practise to use with default drawables?

Tags: android, drawable, convention

Having a specialized folder for default drawable ("drawable" with no screen size extension) would be more intuitive and self explanatory, making it easier to locate files. But will it cause logical errors in runtime?
What is the convention here? do most developers put default drawables in one of the screen-size-specific folders (and if so, which one?) or do most developers create a non-specific "drawable" folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It doesn't cause problems.  Android looks in the "drawable" folder first, and then looks at any other folder as an override.

Comment: As I hoped. I find it much cleaner to do so.

Answer (score 1):

In fact you should put it in `drawable-nodpi` as explained [Here](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html)

Comment: thanks, in my case I want to replace the loog & feel of buttons. I have several 9-patch files which I put in the different dpi-folders, and a 'selector' resource with the different states. my question is about the 'selector', and I wonder - your link says 'nodpi' will not be scaled, does that mean my buttons will not be scaled at all, or since the different 9-patch files are in the scaled folders they will be scaled regardless of where the 'selector' is?

Comment: Didn't think you was talkin about a xml file. In your case, Gabe is right, you have to place it in the drawable folder.